# use *.bmf bitmap font on LWUIt?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, j2mepolish

i make bitmap font with j2mepolish font editor , is it possible to use this bitmap font on LWUIT ?
how ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there is no support for importing j2mepolish bitmaps into LWUIT.